# Can a literal value be passed as a table-valued-parameter in a stored procedure call?

Tags: sql-server

**Background:** I often see *Table-Valued Parameter* as the recommended way to pass a multi-valued parameter into a SQL Server stored procedure, but I have never seen this in practice.

In all the projects I have worked on across several jobs, I typically see multi-valued parameters passed most often as comma-separated lists (pick your delimiter) and occasionally as XML or JSON (which accommodate more complex values). These are typically parsed and used to populate table variables before use, but are sometimes parsed inline (when only referenced once in the stored procedure body).

I suspect the reason that *Table-Valued Parameters* have not been used may be a combination of obscurity, initial learning curve, and perhaps a bit of just plain inconvenience. My question regards the latter.

**Question:** When I create or modify a stored procedure, I prefer to smoke-test it using a single line call like `EXEC MyProcedure TestValue1, TestValue2, TestValue3, ...`, or possibly multiple simple tests like this. For cases where one of the parameters is a table-valued parameter, is there a way to provide a literal value for that parameter?

For example, given the following types and stored procedure definitions:

```
CREATE TYPE IntList AS TABLE(Value INT)
CREATE TYPE StringList AS TABLE(Value NVARCHAR(MAX))

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @IntValues IntList READONLY,
    @StringValues StringList READONLY
AS
    SELECT
        (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM @IntValues) AS MaxInt,
        (SELECT MAX(Value) FROM @StringValues) AS MaxString
```

This can be tested using multiple statements like:

```
DECLARE @IntValues IntList
DECLARE @StringValues StringList
INSERT @IntValues VALUES (1), (2)
INSERT @StringValues VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')
EXEC MyProcedure @IntValues, @StringValues
```

I'd would prefer to test it with a single statement, something like:

```
EXEC MyProcedure (1, 2), ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
-- or
EXEC MyProcedure (VALUES (1), (2)), (VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc'))
```

The above is of course not even syntactically correct, but is there a concise way to inject table parameters literals?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5CeiPvTH)

Comment: No, there is not; you must define (table) variables and pass those.

Comment: Afaik no, your first test scenario is all you can do.

Comment: Just stay with XML or JSON. It will be a single statement.

Comment: I know using TVPs works. Does [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) help? Maybe you need something more flexible for the testing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - That's a nice link. Lots better than several of the other sea-of-text writeups on TVPs. It did show the option of using the implicit default (empty table), which might have some use. Otherwise it seems all are in agreement - separate table variables must be explicitly declared and populated.

Comment: I might be a bit of an old-timer, but it's always been a hustle using TVPs, so i tend to go with just temp tables as "parameters". For more dynamism, one can use `@pTableName` style parameters as well as more or less complex logic to handle dynamic set of columns available. It's still a fair bit of typing going on, but with a lot more flexibility

Comment: @siggemannen yuck, just yuck  that sounds wrong on so many levels, I'd use comma separated variables before I used your method, and I never use comma separated variables. The only concession I make when using table valued parameters is that I will define some generic table types e.g. list of int IDs, list of int IDs with a single string value... So as to avoid a custom table definition for every SP.

Comment: I imagine take up of TVPs would be higher if there were some built in types in the `sys` schema for the common cases of supplying a list of a single type. Sounds like this was a hurdle that was one of the motivations for EF not using this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/

Comment: We have numerous c#-based .net applications, a few vb ones and several old legacy asp apps dating back nearly 20 years; probably only a couple of of the .net apps pass data to the database via a tvp, the vast majority simply pass a json string (some old ones even use xml - cringe) - either by serialising objects in c# or by building the json data manually - it's just easier to test, debug and implement with the json-parsing sql server methods available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus is no, there is no way to insert a TVP literal in a stored procedure call. Separate table variables must be explicitly declared and populated before being passed into the stored procedure call.

A nice TVP tutorial is found in:

- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).